# file_get_contents: не работает функция

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, сделал парсер для сайта, но пару дней назад выдал мне ошибку

> `Warning: file_get_contents(http://mySite.ru/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/site.ru/data/www/site.ru/informer/go.php`

```
/****часть кода*****/
$url = "http://cbu.uz/";

$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

Функция `file_get_contents()` какой бы сайт не вводил, все ровно выдает ошибку.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это про что? Вы какой файл хотите прочитать? Если `file_get_contents(http://mySite.ru/)` -- часть кода, то это вообще бред.

Comment: а хостинг небось бесплатный ?

Comment: @alexz, file_get_contents, fopen способны открывать потоки ввода/вывода по сетевым протоколам.

Comment: @ReinRaus спасибо, не знал.

Answer (score 2):

Учитесь читать сообщения об ошибках.

> failed to open stream: Connection refused in

Это сообщение означает, что не удалось установить соединение с сервером. Либо сайт который вы парсили упал, либо ваш парсер банально забанили.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `curl`.

Answer (score 1):

В php.ini есть опция `allow_url_fopen`. Вот ее сделайте On. Если доступа к php.ini нет, попробуйте создать файлик .htaccess в корне сайта и прописать там:

```
php_flag allow_url_fopen 1
```

Comment: Да ему, похоже, никаких файлов читать не надо. Ответ битовой строки вероятно самый правильный.

Comment: Да. Пожалуй... Просто как вариант сказал....

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые хостеры блокируют эту функцию для своей же безопасности. А некоторые крупные и не очень порталы блокируют эту функцию для того, чтобы не спарсить данные страницы и не создать сайт-подделку.

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет, у меня не работала file_get_contents, то есть не выводил вообще не чего, переменная куда я записывал свой файл, была пустой, я просмотрел код на наличие ошибок, проверил включена ли данная функция в php.ini, но чисто случайно решил указать другой путь вместо https://domen.ru/file.txt, я указал полный локальный путь, то есть /var/www/xxxxxx/data/www/domen.ru/file.txt, у меня все заработало.